# How to construct xpath and test all possible values from a slider

Tags: xpath, robotframework

On the web page, there is a slider which user can click from `min value 1` till `max value 30`, `default value 5`.

[image]
The element:

```
<div tabindex="0" class="ant-slider-handle" role="slider" aria-valuemin="1" aria-valuemax="30" aria-valuenow="16" aria-disabled="false" style="left: 51.7241%; right: auto; transform: translateX(-50%);"></div>
```

Sample Robot Test Case:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     Browser
Library     BuiltIn
Library     OperatingSystem
Library     String
Resource            ../Resources/BrowserFunctions.robot
Suite Setup         Start New Browser
#Test Setup          Test Setup
Test Setup          Open New Page To Server
#Test Teardown       Test Teardown
Suite Teardown      Close Browser

    *** Test Cases ***
    001_Move-Slider
         Verify Page Content before Launch or after Shutdown
         Click Launch Button
         Click 3D Map Button
         Click                ${Point-Cloud-Expand-Group}
         //Click slider from min 1 to max 30
         //should I use a for loop with @list here? please help me.

 

      *** Variables ***
```

How to construct a more dynamic element of that slider. using variable? please help me

Sample website:

```
https://codesandbox.io/s/p92101zymj
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as below if that fits your req using FOR loop:

${sliderValue}=     Get Slider Value    mySlider

then click that element.

Comment: which library for this?

Comment: Its a SwingLibrary. Refer more at - robotframework.org/SwingLibrary/SwingLibrary-1.9.1.html#Get%20Slider%20Value

Comment: I guess it is not applicable, I updated main post the website sample. just found out webpage is built by react.